# Are all events one-shot?

Tags: betrayal-at-baldurs-gate

I finally bought Betrayal in Baldur's Gate and gathered with some friends to play it. Before the haunt, we stumbled with a couple of event cards that seemed to suggest that a Monster should be placed on the board. But we weren't sure.

For example some cards, such as the *Shambling Form*, clearly have a resolution for the "monster" (it explodes).

But some other aren't as clear. The *Zhentarim Opportunist* is one such case. The event clearly mentions an opponent/monster but we don't know what happens with that monster.

[image: A couple of Event cards from Betrayal in Baldur's Gate]

**Are all events one-shot actions (unless specified otherwise)?**

I'm inclined to believe that the text in vent cards is mostly fluff/flavor. And the fact that a "monster" is indicated is just for ambience. That way, the Zhentarim is understood to have left/fled right after the event is revolved (regardless of the result from the attack).

Comment: You think the Haunt is the only danger in this world? Hahahahaha! Oh, you have so much to learn. ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All events are one shot and the "Monster" in the card is mainly flavor text to make it fit into the game more without just being a random mechanic.

Think of it this way, if the card removed the text would it take away from the game for you?

> You man discard this card and an item. If you do not the player to the right rolls a might attack of 4 against you defend with might as normal. If you take damage from this attack take the top 3 cards from the event deck and shuffle this back in.

In general event cards will inform you when they impact the game board in a long term fashion by instructing you to place tokens on the board.